# I can't add multiple line in grid using form tabs

Tags: acumatica

I've been working on Screen IN202500, and I need to make customize grid, and I found out that acumatica only catch the last line I inputted on the grid, here is what I mean
[image: Add new Grid]

When I press Save, the application only save the latest data
[image]

and this is my DAC that linked to InventoryItem

```
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID))]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID,Equal<Current<ItemCotton.inventoryID>>>>))]
    public int? InventoryID { get; set; }

    public class inventoryID : IBqlField{}
```

and this is my BLC Extension

```
    public PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>> CurrentInventoryItem;
    public PXSelect<ItemCotton, Where<ItemCotton.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>> Cotton;
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? Why I onlu get the last line I inputted into the grid?

Comment: add proper key information to your DAC.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(InventoryItem))]
to your DAC class

Answer (score 0):

In your DAC extension, add IsKey = true, if that field uniquely identifies the record.
`[PXDBInt(IsKey=true)]`